# How to make a single line in latex to have more line space?

Tags: spacing, line-spacing, line, underline

In the following code, due to the shape of Q in "Qualification", the upper side of "L" in "Language" stick with the underline of "Further Qualification". Would it be possible to make the line space of the line of "Language" larger (so that the upper side of "L" in "Language" no longer stick with the underline of "Further Qualification") without changing the parameter in spacing (0.9 in this case)?

(I tried with `vspace`, but that does not work.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, pdftex, english, 10.25pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~~~~}


\definecolor{color}{RGB}{22,48,81} 
\setitemize{itemsep=0em,leftmargin=*,labelsep=6.3mm}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{document}

\begin{spacing}{0.9}
\begin{longtable}[l]{p{49mm}p{110mm}}
\arrayrulecolor{color}\toprule
%...
\textbf{\underline{Further Qualifications}}\\
\textbf{Language}\\
%...
\arrayrulecolor{color}\bottomrule 
\end{longtable}
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you could use `\\[2cm]` to have more space, but I wouldn't use underline in a typeset document, it's a typewriter approximation for bold.

Comment: What's the reason for 0.9 spacing?

Comment: Your MWE compiles with an error and if I add a \\ after {Language} to get rid of the error the problem you describe does not appear.

Comment: @egreg The document is my CV which I would like to keep to 2 pages. 0.9 spacing is to make sure that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You can make your comment an answer.

Comment: With the `makecell` package, you also may add the  `\Gape[height correction][depth correction]{text}` command to add some vertical padding to a cell.

Comment: Use a smaller font size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by the 0.9 line spacing,  you should never do that it will cause inconsistent spacing and ugly output, however to answer the question asked, `\\` takes an optional argument so  you could use `\\[2cm]` to have more space, but I wouldn't use underline in a typeset document, it's a typewriter approximation for bold.

Comment: What should I use instead of 0.9 spacing? Nothing at all?

Comment: @Aqqqq Nothing at all is using the spacing for which the font was designed so that is best, sometimes thesis regulations insist you increase it, so if you must you must, using less than 1 typically means that you are specifying that the space between lines of text is less than the size  of large characters like `(` or accented letters, so TeX has no chance to do anything sensible and things will touch or be spaced inconsistently.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to skin a cat...

Here I introduce `\growtop` to place a `\vphantom{X}` that has been *grown* by 3pt above and below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, pdftex, english, 10.25pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[top=1cm, bottom=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~~~~}


\definecolor{color}{RGB}{22,48,81} 
\setitemize{itemsep=0em,leftmargin=*,labelsep=6.3mm}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\growtop{\addstackgap[3pt]{\vphantom{X}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{spacing}{0.9}
\begin{longtable}[l]{p{49mm}p{110mm}}
\arrayrulecolor{color}\toprule
%...
\textbf{\underline{Further Qualifications}}\\
\growtop\textbf{Language}\\
%...
\arrayrulecolor{color}\bottomrule 
\end{longtable}
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could even introtude `\growtop` into the `longtable` specification, so you wouldn't have to manually insert it in the row:

```
\begin{longtable}[l]{>{\growtop}p{49mm}p{110mm}}
\arrayrulecolor{color}\toprule
%...
\textbf{\underline{Further Qualifications}}\\
\textbf{Language}\\
%...
\arrayrulecolor{color}\bottomrule 
\end{longtable}
```